# What are some ways to use my browser, Chrome, as a JavaScript interpreter?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, bookmarks, javascript

I use an online interpreter.  It's just right up there on my favorite's bar.  Very convenient for me....  I'd like to see the error messages my browser will give me rather than the messages the interpreters give, though.  They're crap.  I'm using Chrome, and I'd prefer to continue using chrome.  Should I get an add-on, or is there some kind of built-in error handler that is nice?

Do I have to create a text file and then open the text file via an HTML file or something?  If so, it's way too laborsom, and I'd rather just use my favorites bar.

Comment: Can you link the on-line interpreter?

Comment: yo: http://mochi.github.com/mochikit/examples/interpreter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the "Tools" menu, there's a "JavaScript console" option (accessible by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>`).  Pick it, then type JS in the console window to your heart's content.  The big catch is, for multi-line stuff, you need to say <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  (The JS will run when you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so don't hit it til you've typed all the lines -- or at least all the lines that need to be in a given chunk, like a function.)

Comment: Aweomesauce.  Know any sweet extensions?

Comment: @Wolfpack: I very rarely use extensions with Chrome. It does so much out of the box, that i haven't found the need.  There's a Firebug Lite extension that looks like it might be useful at times, but it's nowhere near as good as the real thing in FF, IMO.  Particularly since Chrome supports a whole bunch of the functionality without any outside extensions.